# Trouble removing all single quotes enclosing keys and values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

My CSV array looks like this (-it's very large so I'm only showing the first 2 elements):

```
<?php $AuscompDataFeed_array = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    '"Manufacturer ID"' => '"MAN-ID-GNRCABNW-02"',
    '"LQ Price"' => '"1.90000000000000000000"',
    '"AvailableQty"' => '"19.00000000000000000000"',
    '"Net Weight"' => '"0.10000000000000000000"',
    '"Item Category Code"' => '"GNR"',
    '"Product Group Code"' => '"CAB"',
    '"Minor Category 1"' => '"CAB-CAT5"',
    '"Vendor Name"' => '""',
    '"Warranty"' => '""',
    '"Dimension"' => '""',
    '"Description1"' => '"2mt Cat5e Cross Network Cable. Compatible to all network ports, desktops and notebooks. Uptp 1000Mbps network speeds."',
    '"Image"' => '"https://redacted.com/uploads/image/GNR-CAB-NW-02-CRS.jpg"',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    '"Manufacturer ID"' => '"K2A"',
    '"LQ Price"' => '"10.00000000000000000000"',
    '"AvailableQty"' => '"86.00000000000000000000"',
    '"Net Weight"' => '"0.50000000000000000000"',
    '"Item Category Code"' => '"ITR"',
    '"Product Group Code"' => '"KBD"',
    '"Minor Category 1"' => '"KBD-WIRED"',
    '"Vendor Name"' => '""',
    '"Warranty"' => '""',
    '"Dimension"' => '""',
    '"Description1"' => '"Itron K2A Keyboard, PS2 Beige"',
    '"Image"' => '"https://redacted.com/uploads/image/ITR-KBD-K2A-WHT-PS2.jpg"',
  ),
```

I tried removing the outermost single quotes from all keys and values of the array, so that the double quotes won't be literals when parsed by most CSV-handling programs, but this returns an empty array so I've probably erred in my regex:

```
foreach ($left as $k => $v){
    foreach ($v as $key => $value){
        //strip $value of double quotes enclosing it
        $value = preg_replace('/^\'/','',$value);
        $value = preg_replace('/\'$/','',$value);
        $left[$k][$key] = $value;

        //strip $key of double quotes enclosing it

        $newkey = preg_replace('/^\'/','',$key);
        $newkey = preg_replace('/\'$/','',$key);

        $left[$k][$newkey] = $left[$k][$key];
        unset($left[$k][$key]);

    }
}
```

How can I remove the outermost single quotes only.  Many fields will have in-field single quotes also, so I have used `^` and `$` to isolate the single quotes of interest.

If you feel there is a more efficient/elegant approach to the problem, then alternative code is also acceptable.

Comment: The single quotes are the delimiters for the string itself and the string starts with a double quote. Why not remove the double quotes instead? `$value = preg_replace('/^"|"$/','',$value);`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Are you able to test that on the array yourself, as I'm getting confusing results?  It's quite a large file, but I've made the input array file available for download [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c7ckti6gtv2fgsh/left.php?dl=0).  When the output comes out, we expect it to be marginally smaller in size as we're only removing quotes, but mine went down from 167 to to 60-something MB and the array got completely warped.  Could be that the complexity of the in-field content is causing breakages without the draconian double quoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error in your regex, but you are trying to replace the first and last [single quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) which are not present in the string, they are enclosing the string.

The strings itself start with a double quote, which you could remove shorting the code to use an alternation `|`

```
$value = preg_replace('/^"|"$/','',$value);
$newkey = preg_replace('/^"|"$/','',$key);
```

The reason that you get an empty array is because [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) returns the unchanged string.

First the same value will be overwritten:

```
$left[$k][$newkey] = $left[$k][$key];
```

Then you will unset that same value as the key has not changed removing all the values:

```
unset($left[$k][$key]);
```